# Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types NUMBER(10,0) and NUMBER(38,0)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are getting the following error while trying to cast a column from varchar to  NUMBER(38,0)
"Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types NUMBER(10,0) and NUMBER(38,0)"

However, on the documentation. Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

***Usage Notes:***

- List item

Only works for string expressions.

***target_data_type must be one of the following:***

- List item

NUMBER (or any of its synonyms)

Comment: [TRY_CAST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_cast): `TRY_CAST( <source_string_expr> AS <target_data_type> )` **source_string_expr** - the expression you are trying to cast is not a string but NUMBER(10,0) based on error message.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the actual code you've tried, but I can reproduce the error message you are seeing by using a number as the first argument or a numeric column, so perhaps you are not using this on a varchar column.

The [docs for TRY_CAST()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_cast) show the syntax:

```sql
TRY_CAST( <source_string_expr> AS <target_data_type> )
```

e.g. this works

```
select try_cast('10.0' as number(10,0))
```

but this doesn't:

```
select try_cast(10.0 as number(10,0))
```

Similarly I can get your exact error like this:

```
with test_data as (select 1000000000 as number_column)
select try_cast(number_column as number) from test_data;


Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types NUMBER(10,0) and NUMBER(38,0)
```

and also with this:

```
select try_cast(1000000000 as number)

Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types NUMBER(10,0) and NUMBER(38,0)
```

Interestingly this works:

```
select cast(1000000000 as number)
```

*This shows it is an `INTEGER` which in Snowflake is a synonym for `NUMBER` which is stored effectively as `number(38,0)` so it's the same thing.*

If your source column is already some smaller precision integer (effectively a float with scale 0) then you don't need to `try_cast()`, just the regular `cast()` should work.

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't makesense that it cannot work with other datatypes other than varchar

Comment: It does work with other datatypes, just not these ones (integer to another integer of different precision). I agree it doesn't make sense because it's not a matter of downscaling or information loss. The error you get when trying to cast a number(10,5) to a number(1,1) for example is very different, about not enough precision.